# How to filter column and plot bunch of files

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 30 files that each of which has 6 columns. I want to plot 2 first columns as my X and Y but considering the points that have zero value(Almost zero because my value is 0.0003) in the 6th column. The columns are float and I need to have comparison on float numbers. The code is below :

```
filenames = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]
files = {}
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        if filename in files:
            continue
        #files[filename] = file.read()
        lines = file.readlines()
        near = [float(line.split()[5]) for line in lines]
        x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
        y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
plt.plot(x[near<=0.0], y[near<=0.0], lw=1.75)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Also I have used a for loop and using numpy to read and plot files but the problem is still alive. the code which I mentioned(using numpy is below):

```
l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]

maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in l])
l = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
for i, d in enumerate(l[::100]):
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
    plt.plot(a[0], a[1], c=cmap.to_rgba(i+1),label=num[-3:], lw=0.75) 
    idx = np.argwhere(a[0] == 0)
    #plt.colorbar(cmap, ticks = c)
    #print(idx)
#plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1)) 

plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.title("Longterm simulation")
plt.plot(a[0],a[1],c='b')
plt.plot(a[0][a[5]<=0.000], a[1][a[5]<=0.000], c='r', lw=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ① get a Boolean array checking the values of a column and ② use that array to index the columns that you want to plot.

E.g.,

```
In [25]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: import numpy as np 
    ...:  
    ...: # prepare some data for the following example
    ...: N = 10000 
    ...: a = np.zeros((N,3)) 
    ...: a[:,0] = np.linspace(0, 10, N) 
    ...: a[:,1] = np.sin(a[:,0]) 
    ...: a[:,2] = np.random.random(N)
    ...:
    ...: # construct a boolean array by testing the values of the last column
    ...: indices = a[:,-1]<0.012
    ...: # plot (as points) the single values where a[n,3]<0.012 
    ...: plt.plot(a[indices,0], a[indices,1], '.') 
    ...: # and, as a visual reference, the complete first columns...
    ...: plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], alpha=0.3) 
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas library for this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file_name") # If Not CSV files, appropriate read fn
df_near = df[df[5]<=0.0]
plt.plot(df[0],df[1])
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Files are not CSV and I have to read them by numpy (it is simple and fast)

Comment: pandas is very fast too, if it is not CSV there are many other read_ functions in the library. What is the filetype?